# does java.math.BigDecimal works with sql server float type

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, bigdecimal

does java.math.BigDecimal works with sql server float type?

my application is not accurate on calculation , what we have decided to do is refactor all the application (over 5 years of development and somthimg like 200 years of development)

my question is if I want touch the application sql does integers who have worked just fine eith an sql type float , would b treated as such when the conversion would b to big decimal and vise versa .

10x !!!!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do ? Do you want to convert java datatype to java.sql type ?

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't make sense. You would have to convert both the SQL columns and the Java code. Without doing both you won't solve anything.